# How to build a dependency that calls a function of another dependency depending on the current project?

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin.android

Explained:
I have a huge project that is built over a solid framework where functions that has to connect to the database works differently depending on a few conditions (in simple terms we can just say its a true/false boolean). In simple terms, when it access the DB, it access either as web service or a direct mysql connection.

Now I am starting to create a Xamarin project (android) and I want to import this framework, however, Xamarin doesn't support mysql... although the framework can make calls to a webservice to get the mysql data, the fact that the mysql code is there it stops my xamarin project from building. I cant even use "#if" because there is still a reference to the mysql dll. How would I go about to split my class dll file so that for this android project doesn't load the mysql dll, just part of the function that calls the web service?
Example of how the function looks like:

```
public static void InsertStuff(object stuff, bool useDirectMysql)
{
    if (useDirectMysql)//I would like that this part only appears/works if its not the xamarin project, however, i can't use #if as the framework dll still has a reference to the mysql dll
    {
        //MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection....
        //insert stuff
    }
    else
    {
        //Insert stuff with a web service function.. (compatible with xamarin)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zdravko provided a nice work around

However, I accomplished what I wanted by literally compiler commenting every single usage or reference of properties, functions, objects and references ("using ...") from the framework. So although it has references to the .dll files in the references part of the project, Visual Studio seems to not compile/emb those dlls that are not used.

My ultimate solution was:

1-Create 2 build configurations, one for the xamarin project and the framework and another for my normal windows programs and the framework.

2-Comment everything not compatible with mobile xamarin (but still keeping the reference on the project)

3-Created a compiler variable like **A**. When I  want to compile my xamarin project, i select the build configuration that just allows the framework and the xamarin, put the **A** in my framework dll and it compiles.

4-Change configuration and remote the **A** when building normal c#/c++/etc programs.

Everything is on the same VS solution.

Comment: No, @ZdravkoDanev provided the correct way to do it... your answer *is* a workaround :-)

Comment: @Jcl No, I its not. His is an answer to a object oriented framework, whereas most of my framework only has static methods. I cant make interfaces and what not. I do have some objects that i could have just moved to another class and done as such, however, 80% of its just static classes and methods using the references.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern for implementing platform specific features goes like this:

- Create an interface in your shared project that has a method InsertStuff.
- Inject the dependency using DI.
- Implement the interface in each of the platform projects accordingly.